# How do I perform a culture-insensitive sort using the DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, datagrid, culture

By default, `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid` will sort String-based columns using a [culture-sensitive sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7zyyk0c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This can cause unexpected results when sorting product numbers that contain hyphens. For example, items will be sorted as 10-199, 103-10, 10-399 rather than 10-199, 10-399, 103-10.

Similar bug reports can be found at http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/121496-sorting-datagrid-containing-dash-hyphen and http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/415793/dataview-sort-ignores-leading-dashes-hyphens-wrong-sort-order.

How can I have the DataGrid sort a column of Strings using a culture-insensitive sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found is to create a new class inheriting from DataGrid and override the [OnSortCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.onsortcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with your own custom sort.